# Regex to match a word only when the line starts with a certain string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I want to make a Regex to match something only when the line starts with a given string. Given the following two lines, I want to match `width` and `height` only in the 1st string:

`frame at x1 y1 width 50 height 200
 rectangle at x1 y1 width 50 height 200`

The closest I got was this:

`(?<=frame\s).*(width|height)`

But this expression is matching everything between `frame` and `200`

[image]

I'm using https://rubular.com/ to test it.

Comment: I think my text wasn't clear, sorry everyone who answered, but I need to capture the words `width` and `height`, and not the actual values. It's for a syntax highlight code extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
`\Aframe.*width\s(?<width>\d+)\sheight\s(?<height>\d+)\z`

In ruby, the result would like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /\Aframe\b.*\swidth\s+(\d+)\s+height\s+(\d+)/
```

```
"frame at x1 y1 width 50 height 200".scan(r).flatten
  #=> ["50", "200"] 
"rectangle at x1 y1 width 50 height 200".scan(r).flatten
  #=> []
"framer at x1 y1 width 50 height 200".scan(r).flatten
  #=> []
"frame at x1 y1 bandwidth 50 height 200".scan(r).flatten
  #=> []
"frame at x1 y1 width 50 midheight 200".scan(r).flatten
  #=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

Is using match groups an option? In your example, the full match is `at x1 y1 width 50 height`, but the match group is just `width`. What do you want to capture, the values for width and height?

If you know the format of the strings (as in, `width` is always before `height`), then you can have a regex like this:

```rb
/\Aframe.*width (?<width>\d+).*height (?<height>\d+)/
```

Comment: Yes, I guess match groups would be a valid option, but I need to capture the words `width` and `height` and not the values. They could be in any order.